After upgrading flutter to 3.27, App stuck on launch on android, giving no errors in console
Flutter Upgrade Issue - Android Impeller issue on version 3.27.
I upgraged to flutter 3.27 and when installed my flutter app onmy samsung galaxy note 10 lite, it stuck on black screen, there are no errors showing on console.

Resolved this issue by :
installing my app using
flutter run flutter run --no-enable-impeller
or while running from android studio in:
Go to Edit Configurations-> add run args-> --no-enable-impeller-> Save.

Please edit your question if you want to add more information instead of adding more information as an answer.

It works when you run the app but after closing the app and open it from the icon is still black screen. Any way to keep that and after stopping the app and when you want to create an app bundle?

@AndreasHadjimamas For now downgraded my flutter version again until flutter team resolves this issue. Or you can refer this link, i didn't try it though... https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/160228#issuecomment-2542459067

Thank you for your response. I applied this --no-enable-impeller through my AndroidManifest.xml and seems to be working for all cases
<meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.EnableImpeller"
            android:value="false" />



